# Why the size equals the data that has been added in the binary tree after calling AddNode() function?

Tags: c, function, data-structures, binary-tree

When I enter a number lets say 20 as **data** the **size** also becomes (the number which is 20 in this case +1). The entered **data** always assigned to the **size**, Why?!
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
//#include <memory>
//#include <alloc.h>

typedef struct node{
    struct node *right;
    struct node *left;
    int data;
}Node;

typedef struct tree{
    Node* root;
    int size;
}Tree;

void CreateTree(Tree *pt){
    pt->root = NULL;
    pt-> size = 0;
}

void AddNode(Tree *pt, int data){
    Node *parent, *current = pt->root;
    Node *pnew = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    pnew-> data = data;
    pnew->right = NULL;
    pnew->left = NULL;
    pt->size++;

    if(!current){
        pt->root = pnew;
        return;
    }
    while(current){
        parent = current;
        if(pnew->data > current->data)
            current = current->right;
        else
            current = current->left;
    }

    if(pnew->data > parent->data)
        parent->right = pnew;
    else
        parent->left = pnew;
}

int TreeSize(Tree *pt){
    return pt->size;
}

int main(){

    int data;
    Tree *t;
    CreateTree(&t);

    printf("Enter the Element: ");
    scanf("%d",&data);
    AddNode(&t, data);

    printf("The Tree has %d element(s).\n", TreeSize(&t));

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

> The size should be increased by 1 only when I call AddNode() not equals to the data every time.

Comment: That compiles for you? Do you at least get warnings about incompatible types?

Comment: Is `Tree *t;` in `main` a typo or are you actually using this code?

Comment: You have lots of problems with incorrect pointer types. If you pass `&t` to a function, the argument needs to be `Tree **`, not `Tree *`.

Comment: I'm actually using this code, but it compiles for me without any warnings about incompatible types & I don't know why. Now it's working properly after deleting *
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You never allocate any space for `t`.

Comment: If you weren't getting any warnings, you need to increase the warning level of your compiler.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers require different options to produce the same results

Comment: in the function: `void CreateTree(Tree *pt){`  The parameter `pt` has never been set to point to memory that the application owns ( for instance via a call to `malloc()`) so writing to offsets, using that pointer (to pointer) is undefined behavior.

Comment: OT: regarding: `Node *pnew = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));`  1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
AddNode(&t, data);
```

This makes the parameter `t` (as seen be the called function) to be a `pointer to pointer`, however, the called function is treating it as a `pointer`  So any writes to it (and any writes to offsets) results in undefined behavior.

In this case by overwriting the variable `size`